# cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Tags: c, casting, memcpy, strncpy

Well, I have to revive a question that was answered here before.  I've made some changes for other reasons and now I have a problem again.  Here is the relevant details:

```
volatile char RxBuffer1[NEMA_BUFFER_LENGTH];
uint32_t NEMA_TypeStart;
char NEMA_Type[10];
uint32_t len;
...

memcpy(NEMA_Type,(const char*)RxBuffer1[NEMA_TypeStart], len);
```

With the cast I get the error shown in the subject line.  Without the cast I get:

> passing argument 2 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast

Note the same thing happens if I use strncpy instead.  So I'm stumped.  I thought I understood that memcpy uses void*.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass addresses to `memcpy`. I would assume you want:

```
memcpy(NEMA_Type,(const char*) &RxBuffer1[NEMA_TypeStart], len);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thank you. I think I'm a victim of trying to learn to fast.  I (thought) I understood that the string variable really IS a pointer in C.  in other words I thought RxBuffer1[n] == &RxBuffer1 + n

Comment: `RxBuffer`'s not a string, it's an array. You can do, for example, `Rxbuffer[2]=RxBuffer[0]`, so these must be the values of the array's elements.

Comment: and don't put the cast in there, it just distracts from the problem

Comment: Actually the cast is necessary since the buffer is volatile.

Answer (score 1):

Its been awhile, but I think you need to say this instead...

```
memcpy(NEMA_Type, &RxBuffer1[NEMA_TypeStart], len);
```

You could also say...

```
memcpy(NEMA_Type, RxBuffer1 + NEMA_TypeStart, len);
```